# Не могу найти свою ошибку в парсере Python

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, lxml

Всем привет. Начал практиковаться в парсинге, собственно не имея весомого опыта за спиной, парсил себе в удовольствие обычные сайты и дошел до Яндекс-Маркета. До последнего не хотел писать сюда, потому что изначально понимаю абсурдность идеи- "парсить маркет человеку без опыта", но ответ очень интересен.
В общем, ближе к сути:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}

base_url = 'https://market.yandex.ru/catalog--kholodilniki/71639/list?hid=15450081&onstock=1&local-offers-first=0'


def get_html(base_url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(base_url, headers=headers)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.content, 'lxml')
```

В момент поиска div-a, интерпретируется `None`. Но этот див определенно присутствует, в панели разработчика, в показанной разметке

```
        div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_1DqdIFuq1G'})
        print(div)
    else:
        print('error')


get_html(base_url, headers)
```

До этого писал парсер по-другому, без сессии и хедеров, пошарив инфу, использовал местами фрагменты чужого парсера, понадеялся на то, что это поможет от защиты. 
Часто при дальнейшем поиске глубже, методами .find/.find_all. (в моем случае там теги ul, в нем li, как минимум в такой конструкции:

```py
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_1DqdIFuq1G'}).find('ul')
```

уже появляется ошибка

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Более детальные обозначения с атрибутами, выдают то же самое. Где-то вычитал что это защита все.

В общем, искренне прошу не закидывать меня мокрыми тряпками, а понять по возможности (мокрыми не только от попадания на них отходов-продуктов жизнедеятельности человека, а еще и от воды в моем вопросе). Я абсолютно понимаю, что многого еще не знаю и возможно мой взгляд узок.

Comment: То, что в панели разработчика != то, что пришло с сервера. С сервера мог пройти: 1) html с тем тегом 2) json внутри html с тем тегом 3) javascript с тем тегом 4) был выполнен ajax запрос и в ответ получен тот тег (как html или json) 5) и т.п. Для 2), 3), 4) мог быть сделан рендеринг html. Нужно скачать скриптом страницу и посмотреть глазами тот тег. Еще, можно посмотреть на панели разработчика на вкладке Сети -- там и запросы и данные что пришли. Кст, загрузил ту страницу и там не нашел тот класс, скорее всего класс уникальный для разных машин или вообще рандомно строится новыми запросами

Comment: А что именно Вам необходимо спарсить? Я бы помог, да не знаю чем :) Приведите ожидаемый вывод программы на некоторых данных.

Comment: Возможно, данные, которые вы ищите, отрисовываются `javascript`. В таком случае Вам нужен либо эмулятор браузера (`selenium`), либо ревёрсить `javascript` и смотреть, как он эти теги отрисовывает.